# How to make conditional judgments on several columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

[image]

I want to calculate the number of devices sold to hospitals by sales people.

There are several scenarios:

1. A sale corresponds to a hospital and has only one row of data, which indicates that this sale sold a piece of equipment to this hospital, like the mike row in the table.
2. A sale corresponds to a hospital, but there are two rows of data (Lines like andrew or duke), if the Signing time and Arrival time of one of the rows of data are empty (exapmle: Nan, NaT, None), and also the commission of this row is a multiple of 10000, then this salesperson has sold only one device to this hospital
3. Two different salespeople for the same hospital, that means that two salespeople sold 0.5 units each.

The final output table I need looks like this：

[image]

How can I do this with pandas?

Comment: Sorry, not understand `also the commission of this row is a multiple of 10000` - seems output forget for this condition or not important for ouput?

Comment: In my input form, I list the commissions in multiples of 10,000

Comment: Hmmm, not understand. I see all data multiplied by 10,000 without 20,300. But this row has `Signing time and Arrival time` not equal `NaN, NaT`, so count for `duke` in final df. So not understand it how test `multiplied by 10,000`

Comment: If I want to add a column of commissions to the output table with the sum of each sales' commissions, how should I modify the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
#test all rows with at least one non NaN, Nat, None values
m = df[['Signing time', 'Arrival time']].notna().any(axis=1)

#get sums per Hospitals of Trues
df['Number of equipment'] = df.assign(m = m).groupby(['Hospital'])['m'].transform('sum')

#remove duplicates per both columns
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Sales','Hospital'])

#divide by number of Hospitals
df['Number of equipment'] /= df['Hospital'].map(df['Hospital'].value_counts())

#aggreagte sum if Sales are duplicates
df1 = df.groupby('Sales', sort=False, as_index=False)['Number of equipment'].sum()

#filter only columns if Sales are not duplicated
#df1 = df[['Sales','Number of equipment']]
```

Comment: df['Number of equipment'] /= df['Hospital'].map(df['Hospital'].value_counts()) ,   "/="  Is this the correct way to write it?

Comment: @Andrew sure, it is same like `df['Number of equipment'] = df['Number of equipment'] / df['Hospital'].map(df['Hospital'].value_counts())`

Comment: ，One more case needs to be added:  If there is a line where the value of commission is less than 0, then the number of equipment in this line is set to 0, regardless of whether Signing time and Arrival time have values。How to modify the above code ?

Comment: @Andrew I have holiday on phone only, so best post new question.

Comment: OK，thanks very much.